# Convexity of a ${\rm tanh}^{-1}\ (x) / x$?

Tags: convex-analysis

I want to prove that the function:

$f(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow x} \dfrac{\text{tanh}^{-1}(y)}{y}$

is convex in $(-1,1)$, where $\text{tanh}^{-1}()$ is the inverse hyperbolic tangent function. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit "tedious" but maybe you can try from calculating the 2nd derivative of the function

Comment: Isn't $f(x)$ simply $\dfrac{\tanh^{-1}(x)}{x}$ except when $x=0 $ ?   have you considered Taylor series?

Comment: I computed the second derivative but did not manage to show it is positive. Yes, the limit is just there in order to handle the case $x=0$. I have not used Taylor series, I will try that thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\operatorname{arctanh} x= \sum_{k=1,3,5,...} {1 \over k} x^k$, so
$f(x) = \sum_{k=1,3,5,...} {1 \over k} x^{k-1}$.

Hence $f''(x) = \sum_{k=3,5,7,...} {1 \over k} (k-1)(k-2) x^{k-3}$ and it is straightforward to observe that $f''(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: You need to divide by x first.